# Width mismatch vhdl at constant declaration

Tags: vhdl

I really don't get it. It's a simple constant vector declaration.

If it's a vector, shouldn't it be allowed to have any value (3 in my case)?

Error:

```
  Width mismatch, location has width 2, value 3
```

At code:

```
    constant s0: std_logic_vector := "000";
```

Comment: The declaration `constant s0: std_logic_vector := "000";` is legal, resulting in `std_logic_vector` with range 0 to 2, so the error must occur due to some non-disclosed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was elsewhere in the code where I tried to calculate with a vector of wrong width. The problem was that the error was reported at the constant declaration and not at the place of error

Answer (score -1):

Just do it:

```
constant s0: std_logic_vector(0 to 2) := "000";
```

or

```
constant s0: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000";
```

or

```
constant s0: std_logic_vector(CONSTANT_X to CONSTANT_X+2) := "000";
```

You cannot declare a constant/signal without RANGE (size). Unranged style only support in function and you must assign it into signal/variable with range.

```
function cast_v(vector_in: std_logic_vector; OUT_W: integer) return std_logic_vector is
    constant IN_W : integer := vector_in'length;
    constant CAST_W : integer := OUT_W - IN_W;
    variable cast_vector: std_logic_vector(CAST_W-1 downto 0);
    variable vector_out : std_logic_vector(OUT_W-1 downto 0);
  begin
    gen_bits: for i in CAST_W-1 downto 0 loop
      cast_vector(i) := vector_in(IN_W-1);
    end loop gen_bits;
    vector_out := cast_vector & vector_in;
    return vector_out;
  end cast_v;
```

And one more thing, sir. Please read carefully your VHDL cookbook.

Comment: You *can* declare a constant without range, with an initialiser, as Morten Zilmer has already commented below the question